# Slide up view in a horizontal UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiscrollview

I currently have a horizontal scrollview where the next content is partially displayed. For some of these views, they need to be able to pull up and expose more content. What's the best way to build this sort of interaction? I see that I can capture scrollview events via the scrollview delegate, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

[image: UIScrollView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the scrollview height up to whatever height you want the view to be able to move to/expand.

Then, add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the scrollview, and detect when the movement is 'up', and move the views as necessary.